# Adjust intraclass correlation for measurement error

Tags: measurement-error, intraclass-correlation, adjustment

It's been known [since Spearman (1904)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correction_for_attenuation) that one can adjust an observed Pearson correlation for measurement error using this formula (R code with **tidyverse** attached):

```
true_r = observed_r / sqrt(rel_x * rel_y)
```

Thus, for instance, if we have an observed correlation of .4, and reliabilities of x and y of .6 and .8, we get:

```
true_r = 0.577 = .4 / sqrt(.6 * .8)
```

My question is: how does one do the equivalent correction for an intraclass correlation? I know, people normally use ICC as a measure of reliability, but I need to use it as a metric of within group similarity across raters.

Here things get complicated because there are multiple types of ICC, as well as single and average versions (following [the taxonomy in **psych** package](http://personality-project.org/r/html/ICC.html), at least). In my case, I am interested in the single rater case, type irrelevant (values are identical for my purposes).

Suppose we have 2 targets rated each 10 times. Suppose their true scores are 0 and -1, respectively. We can easily simulate some data for this and calculate the ICC values:

```
set.seed(1)
n = 10
testdf = data_frame(
  a = rnorm(n),
  b = rnorm(n, mean = -1)
)
testdf
# A tibble: 10 x 2
        a       b
    <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 -0.626  0.512 
 2  0.184 -0.610 
 3 -0.836 -1.62  
 4  1.60  -3.21  
 5  0.330  0.125 
 6 -0.820 -1.04  
 7  0.487 -1.02  
 8  0.738 -0.0562
 9  0.576 -0.179 
10 -0.305 -0.406 
psych::ICC(testdf %>% t())
Call: psych::ICC(x = testdf %>% t())

Intraclass correlation coefficients 
                         type  ICC   F df1 df2     p lower bound upper bound
Single_raters_absolute   ICC1 0.26 4.5   1  18 0.049      -0.026           1
Single_random_raters     ICC2 0.26 4.5   1   9 0.064      -0.027           1
Single_fixed_raters      ICC3 0.26 4.5   1   9 0.064      -0.040           1
Average_raters_absolute ICC1k 0.78 4.5   1  18 0.049      -0.343           1
Average_random_raters   ICC2k 0.78 4.5   1   9 0.064      -0.355           1
Average_fixed_raters    ICC3k 0.78 4.5   1   9 0.064      -0.620           1

 Number of subjects = 2     Number of Judges =  10
```

So, for single raters we get .26. The expected value is actually .33, which one sees if one uses a larger sample size:

```
n2 = 10e3

testdf2 = data_frame(
  a = rnorm(n2),
  b = rnorm(n2, mean = -1)
)

psych::ICC(testdf2 %>% t())
Call: psych::ICC(x = testdf2 %>% t())

Intraclass correlation coefficients 
                         type  ICC    F df1   df2 p lower bound upper bound
Single_raters_absolute   ICC1 0.33 4946   1 19998 0        0.09           1
Single_random_raters     ICC2 0.33 4970   1  9999 0        0.09           1
Single_fixed_raters      ICC3 0.33 4970   1  9999 0        0.09           1
Average_raters_absolute ICC1k 1.00 4946   1 19998 0        1.00           1
Average_random_raters   ICC2k 1.00 4970   1  9999 0        1.00           1
Average_fixed_raters    ICC3k 1.00 4970   1  9999 0        1.00           1

 Number of subjects = 2     Number of Judges =  10000
```

So far, so good. Now, imagine there is some measurement error in the estimates above. In fact, suppose we add some random measurement error corresponding to reliabilities from .9 to .1. Then we get this:

```
#reduce reliability while preserving distribution
reduce_reliability = function(x, reliability) {
  x * sqrt(reliability) + rnorm(length(x), mean = 0, sd = (sqrt(1 - reliability)))
}

#loop and get values
rels = seq(.9, .1, by = -.1)
names(rels) = rels
ICC_noise = map_dbl(rels, function(r) {
  #copy original
  tmp = testdf2

  #add error
  tmp$a = tmp$a %>% reduce_reliability(reliability = r)
  tmp$b = tmp$b %>% reduce_reliability(reliability = r)

  #ICC
  psych::ICC(tmp %>% t()) %>% .$results %>% .[[1, 2]]
})
ICC_noise

   0.9    0.8    0.7    0.6    0.5    0.4    0.3    0.2    0.1 
0.3048 0.2845 0.2602 0.2187 0.2047 0.1688 0.1357 0.0902 0.0420
```

So, we see an expected decline in the values with increasing measurement error, but how does one adjust this back so we always get .33 here? Dividing by `sqrt(reliability)` as with the Pearson correlation gives incorrect results:

```
ICC_noise / sqrt(rels)
  0.9   0.8   0.7   0.6   0.5   0.4   0.3   0.2   0.1 
0.322 0.316 0.317 0.292 0.279 0.271 0.242 0.211 0.166 

ICC_noise / rels
  0.9   0.8   0.7   0.6   0.5   0.4   0.3   0.2   0.1 
0.339 0.353 0.379 0.377 0.395 0.428 0.441 0.472 0.525
```

So, appears one has to use a different formula. However, I have been unable to find one.